# Is it possible to use word2Vec to derive hyperonymy (hyponymy or ISA relation)?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

It's easy to have hyperonymy in WordNet, e.g. to know that "tea" is a case of "beverage". Is it possible to use word2Vec in this way?

Comment: Great question and I'm interested in the answer too! I hope you get some good replies here

Answer (score -1):

A paper entitled "[Dependency-Based Word Embeddings](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-2050.pdf)" found that word embeddings that defined context using dependency-based parsing generated [cohyponyms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cohyponym). For example, "florida" was embedding near  "texas", "louisiana", "georgia", "california", and "carolina".

Comment: But that's kind of like synonym. It fact, it's easy to cluster words in word2vec. I wonder if, it's possible to get the word for that cluster. For example, it should be "state" for "texas", "georgia".